# Jquery + IE10 - onclick event attached to submit button never fires

Tags: javascript, jquery, windows-7, onclick, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to execute a function when user clicks on submit button. In this example I don't allowed the form submission. All browsers are ok with that but IE10 always submits.
This is my JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
                  $('#_mysubmit').click(function() {
                       return foo();
                  }) 
});

function foo() {
      alert('sth!');
      return false;
}
```

And this is the html code:

```
<form action="#" id="myForm" method="post">
    First Name: <input value="John" id="firstName"><br/>
    Last Name: <input value="Doe" id="lastName"><br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" id="_mysubmit">
</form>
```

And this is the fiddle where I'm testing it: http://jsfiddle.net/TGmpc/

I know it's simple but I can't make it work in IE10. Other browsers has no problem with it, even former IE versions.
Testing on Windows 7 using IE10 and JQuery 1.10.1.

Note: Using this is not an option:
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="..." />

Comment: Visit http://jsfiddle.net/TGmpc/show/ and it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

You're handling the submission of a form, why not use the submit event?

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    $('#myForm').submit(function() {
        return foo();
    }) 
});

function foo() {
    alert('sth!');
    return false;
}
```

Unable to test due to jsfiddle not working in IE10 for me.

Comment: Remember, you can visit the `/show/` URL (without the IDE) to basically view it plainly in any browser

Answer (score 0):

There's something wrong with jQuery 1.10.1 in jsfiddle. Switch to 1.9 and it works fine. Maybe that's your problem?